# Replace Specific Columns with Text+Variable

Tags: excel, vba

i have a list which is imported, all Datablocks are in A underneath. Every block starts with Block=1 then Block=2 and so on. For the Export in needs to be replaced to [Block1] for the whole document.
so code should be like:

The imported Data is like this:
[image]
and after the Import it looks like this:
[image]

Only the first row must be changed.

THE FOLLOWING CODE ISNT WORKING AT ALL; ITS JUST MY IDEA HOW IT WOULD WORK BUT I DONT KNOW THE NEEDED COMANDS:

```
Sub Replace()

Dim XC As Range

For Each XC In Worksheets("Export").UsedRange

If XC.Text = "Block=X" Then
  XC.Replace to [Block1] 
 ' But it needs to be in the next Block: [Block2] and so on.

End If


End Sub
```

Thanks if anybody can help.

I don't know how to please with a variable.

Comment: Can you share with us a sample of the input data, and the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Test()

Dim XC As Range
Dim i As Long

i = 1

For Each XC In Worksheets("Export").UsedRange
If XC.Text = "Test=" + CStr(i) Then 'Debug.Print ("Test" + CStr(i))
XC.Value = "[Test" + CStr(i) + "]"


i = i + 1

End If

Next XC

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter inside your loop. Initialize as 1 outside and then increase it. Something like this may work:

```
Dim XC As Range
Dim i As Long

i = 1
For Each XC In Worksheets("Export").UsedRange
    If XC.Text = "Block=X" Then
        XC.Replace "Block=X", "Block=" & i
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next XC
```

Answer (score 0):

This would give you the exact expected output, based on your example input.

```
Sub test()
    'this is built on the assumption the table is top left of the sheet
    Dim no_of_cols as Long, last_row as Long, output_row as Long, rw as Long, cl as Long
    With ActiveSheet
        no_of_cols = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        output_row = last_row + 2
        For rw = 2 To last_row
            For cl = 1 To no_of_cols
                .Cells(output_row, 1) = .Cells(1, cl).Value & "=" & .Cells(rw, cl).Value
                output_row = output_row + 1
            Next
            output_row = output_row + 1 ' inserts blank line
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```